# Why are Radon measures that agree on closed balls equal?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a task to prove that if two Radon measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on closed balls in $\Bbb{R}^n$ then they are equal. It's given as a corollary of Vitali covering theorem, or to be precise, the corollary of this fact that for Radon measure $\mu$ for $\forall \epsilon>0$ we can find balls $\{B_i\}$, such that $\mu(A)\leq\sum_{i}\mu(B_i)\leq\mu(A)+\epsilon$. I understand how this fact above follows from Vitali covering theorem, but cannot get how to use it to prove that the measures are equal.

Comment: Closed balls generate the Borel $\sigma$ algebra. You need only show that if things agree on a generating set they agree on the entire algebra.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Only problem is that this is false in general. It is, however, true if the generating set is closed under finite intersections. But this does not hold here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your question, the "corollary" is useless: you did not say anything about the covering of $A$ by $B_i$. The existence of a ball of measure equal to $\mu(A)$, somewhere in the space, is of little consequence.

An important point is that such balls *cover* $A$ up to a subset of measure zero.

Let's apply the covering lemma to the measure $\mu+ \nu$. Then $A$ is covered by balls $B_i$ up to a null set for *both* measures, and 
$$ 
\sum\mu(B_i) +  \sum\nu(B_i) \le  \mu(A) + \nu(A)+\epsilon$$ 
The term on the left is just $2\sum\mu(B_i)\ge 2\mu(A)$. Thus 
$$2\mu(A)\le \mu(A) + \nu(A)+\epsilon$$
which yields $\mu(A)\le \nu(A)$. By symmetry, the reverse inequality also holds.